# Smallest positive integer $M$ in a matrix with given pattern

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, algorithms, pattern-recognition

A square matrix $A$ of $N*N$ contains $-1,1$ only. I can swap any two elements in the array as many times a I want. What is the minimum positive integer $M$ such that $A[i][j]=1$ for all pairs of $(i,j)$ where $|i-j|>M$.

Some observations :

1.If it's a diagonal matrix, ,then $M$ will be $0$.

2.If it has no $1$ in it then answer will $N-1$ as no matter how many shifts I do,there will still be some $-1$'s outside the main diagonal, so the $M$ won't become $0$.

Eg : $N=3$

\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & -1 \\
    -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Now the smallest $M=2$. But if I swap $A[3][1]$ , $A[3][3]$ the matrix becomes 
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Now the smallest $M=1$.

How do I find the smallest $M$ ? Is there a pattern to this ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer only depends on the number of $-1$s. If the number of $-1$s fit in the main diagonal of the matrix, the answer is 0. If the number of $-1$s fit in the $first$ $2k+1$ ($k < n$) diagonals (the main diagonal and $k$ diagonals immediately above and $k$ below the main diagonal), then the answer is k.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "fits in first $2k+1 (k<n)$" and can you explain with given example ? And what about swaps ?

Comment: The positions i=j constitute the main diagonal. The positions i=j-1 constitute the diagonal just above the main diagonal. Then comes the diagonal i=j-2 and so on. The k th diagonal above the main diagonal is represented by i=j-k. Similarly the k th diagonal below the main diagonal is given by i=j+k. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, I got that part. Can you please explain your solution with the example given in the question?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment. So in your example you cannot swap all -1s and fit them in the diagonal. Diagonal contains only 3 spots. But you can swap the -1s and fit them in 3 (k=1)diagonals, since the 3 diagonals together contain 7 spots and there are only five -1s. So the answer is 1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There's one more thing : How do I find the $K$ using given number of $-1$'s ?

Comment: Programmatically you can find it by iterating from 0 to n-1. For writing a closed form solution, I believe you can find the total number of slots given some k. For example, if you have n=10, and k = 3. The total number of slots = 10 + 2(9+8+7). For a general k, it is simple to get a closed form expression for the number of slots. Then, you can write "if number of slots for k-1 < the number of -1s <= number of slots for k", then the answer is k.